# Sublime Text 3 Tab Color Based on File Type?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have many similarly named files in my project, e.g. 'items.create.html', 'items.create.controller.js' and 'items.create.scss', and I want to easily find the right one by simply color-coding tabs (maybe even putting custom icons?) based on the file type.

Is that possible?

Is there a package I can install? Maybe hack it on my own?

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible. The [Phoenix theme](https://github.com/netatoo/phoenix-theme) is able to change tabs colors based on a user setting. But for me it doesn't work with syntax specific settings (fileTypes),

Comment: This! so sooo helpful! I always mix up my tabs, with like 16 open tabs..it's so hard to keep track, which is which

Answer (score 4):

It is not perfect but the best "solution" I've found so far is to add a ***Syntax specific setting* to change the *color scheme*** for every filetype in which you want to have a different tab color. **This is not a good solution as it also changes the background color for each filetype**, so I hope someone finds a better answer.

Note 1: to add a *synyax specific setting* open a file (for example a *.css* file) and then use the menu *Preferences > Settings-more > Syntax-specific*. This way the settings you add will only be set for *css* files.

Note 2: in addition to the default *color schemes*, you can create your own and change the *background* property as you like.

Example screenshot:

[image: Sublime text tab color based on file types example]

Example settings:
For javascript:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Zenburnesque (SL).tmTheme",
}
```

For css:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Dawn (SL).tmTheme"
}
```

For html:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Cobalt (SL).tmTheme"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Possible

The following resources will help, **no packages needed**

1. [Change Color Scheme Depending On File Type Open](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2619)

   At the very least you can just use different themes based on the file type. Or you can duplicate your favorite theme and modify it to look slightly different.
2. [How do I change the background tab color? It's too subtle](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5630)

   This resource only talks about editing the default template, but I don't see why this can't be done to any other theme (might take a some tinkering)